# Programmatically expand SwiftUI List with children

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, expand

`SwiftUI.List` creates lovely lists with disclosure chevrons for children. However: how would I tell it to expand all children by default (i.e. programmatically)?

I can’t use `DiscloseGroup` because I have an unknown number of levels of children.